# TypeScript discriminating union - parameter of discrimating property type

Tags: typescript

I have the following definitions:

```
interface Dog {
  bark(): void;
  type: 'dog';
}

interface Cat {
  meow(): void;
  type: 'cat';
}

type Animal = Cat | Dog;
```

Now I would like to make a function that uses `Animal.type` as a parameter:

```
function useAnimalType(type: string) {}
```

In this example, I used `string`, but I really mean `'cat' | 'dog'`. I realize I could write out all the possible `type` of `Animal`, but imagine a scenario when there are hundreds of animal types defined in `Animal`. How do I reuse the `Animal.type` as a parameter here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can retrieve the type of a field in another object type by using bracket notation. For your example, simply:

```
function useAnimalType(type: Animal["type"]) {}
```

would suffice. In such case, `Animal["type"]` is inferred to be `"cat" | "dog"`.